# Splice and shift functions not working as expected in recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm writing my first lines of `JS` code, now I'm trying to do an easy recursive function.

I know `splice()` and `shift()` removes the item they extract.

I'm having troubles here:

```
function sub (...par) { // It could take an arbitrary number of parameters

    if (par.length >= 2)
    {
        var val = par.shift();
        //val = par.splice(0,1);
        return val - sub(par);
    }
    else 
    {
        /*EDIT*/ //return par[0];
        return -par[0];
    }
}
```

Now if I run: `sub (17,7)` I correctly got `10`, but If I run `sub(17,7,3)` instead of getting `8` I got `NaN`.

**fixed** like this thanks to Jonas Wilms help:

```
function sub (...par) { // It could take an arbitrary number of parameters

    if (par.length >= 2)
    {
        var val = par.shift();
        //val = par.splice(0,1);
        return val - sub(...par);
    }
    else 
    {
        /*EDIT*/ //return par[0];
        return -par[0];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You have to spread on the recursive call:

```
  return val - sub(...par);
```

Otherwise `par` inside of the called `sub` will be an array containing an array, and doing substraction on that will fail.

However the whole thing is way more elegant if you take the first parameter directly:

```
  function sub(head, ...rest) {
    if(!rest.length) return head;
    return head - sub(...rest);
  }
```

However one should note that you might not get the result you expect with that, as you calculate the right side before the left, so

```
  sub(1, 2, 3)
```

equals

```
 1 - (2 - 3)
```

and thats 2.

I think it would be clearer if `sub(1, 2, 3)` would equal `1 - 2 - 3` that can be achieved with:

```
 function sub(...rest) {
   if(rest.length === 1) return rest[0];
   const last = rest.pop();
   return sub(...rest) - last;
 }
```

Or without recursion:

```
  const sub = (...args) => args.reduce((a, b) => a - b);
```

Comment: Thanks, it's really claryfying

Answer (score 0):

Consider this total implementation that returns a correct value even when zero arguments are used

```js
const sub = (a = 0, b = 0, ...more) =>
  more.length === 0
    ? a - b
    : sub (a - b, ...more)

console.log(sub(17))         // 17
console.log(sub(17,7))       // 17 - 7 = 10
console.log(sub(17,7,3))     // (17 - 7) - 3 = 7
console.log(sub(17,7,3,2))   // ((17 - 7) - 3) - 2 = 5
console.log(sub(17,7,3,2,4)) // (((17 - 7) - 3) - 2) - 4 = 1
console.log(sub())           // 0
```

The above program is **left associative** whereas the program below is **right-associative** -

```js
const sub = (a = 0, ...more) =>
  more.length === 0
    ? a
    : a - sub (...more)

console.log(sub(17))         // 17
console.log(sub(17,7))       // 17 - 10 = 10
console.log(sub(17,7,3))     // 17 - (7 - 3) = 13
console.log(sub(17,7,3,2))   // 17 - (7 - (3 - 2)) = 11
console.log(sub(17,7,3,2,4)) // 17 - (7 - (3 - (2 - 4))) = 15
console.log(sub())           // 0
```